# How to pass column name into the level parameter in groupby function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I having trouble passing level name in groupby function in Pandas. My dataframe is very large with 34 columns.

```
Shpr_Resi_Ratio = (
    data[data.Resi == 'Y'].groupby(level='Shpr_ID').count() /
    data.groupby(level='Shpr_ID').count()
)
```

Error

```
2523                     raise ValueError('level name %s is not the name of the '
-> 2524                                      'index' % level)
   2525             elif level > 0 or level < -1:
   2526                 raise ValueError('level > 0 or level < -1 only valid with '

ValueError: level name Shpr_ID is not the name of the index
```

How to fix the problem

**Sample dataframe**

```
 Stop_Type  Resi    Co_Name Lat Lng Cust_ID Qty Phone   Shpr_ID
0   D   N   ROBECO HONG KONG    22.283737   114.156219  NaN 1   0   348772830.0
1   D   N   NIKKO ASSET MANAGEMENT HK LIMI  22.283737   114.156219  NaN 1   85239403900 811633127.0
2   D   N   CFA INSTITUTE HONG KONG OFFICE  22.283737   114.156219  NaN 1   8.52E+11    22901265.0
3   D   N   VICTON REGISTRATIONS LIMITED    22.283144   114.155122  NaN 1   85228450884 269243180.0
4   D   N   DING FUNG LIMITED   22.282634   114.155592  NaN 1   85223919307 100724987.0
5   D   N   QUAM LIMITED    22.281737   114.156819  NaN 6   85222172878 193550630.0
6   D   N   CANARA BANK 22.281737   114.156819  NaN 1   85225291398 911433524.0
7   D   N   GIA HONG KONG   22.281737   114.156819  NaN 1   85223030075 90470655.0
8   D   Y   ZAABA CAPITAL LIMITED   22.281737   114.156819  NaN 1   8772461225  260103490.0
9   D   N   FIRESTAR DIAMOND HK 22.280644   114.158432  NaN 1   25303677    659886588.0
```

I am trying to calculate a ratio  two cloumns .

```
Resi    Shpr_ID Shpr_ID_Ratio
Y   577030944   0.933333333
N   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
Y   577030944   0.933333333
```

Comment: Can you add a sample data like `Shpr_Resi_Ratio.head().iloc[:,:5]`. Is your index multiindex()?If not  try `level = 0 `

Comment: @Bharathshetty, the output top_Type Resi Co_Name Lat Lng
Shpr_ID     
1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
30.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
132.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
148.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
156.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Comment: Im sorry it was suppose to be `data.head(10).iloc[:,:5]`. Add this in your qn

Comment: @Bharathshetty,added  the output

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. This is certainly not the way of doing it.

Comment: @Bharathshetty, i am trying to calculate a ratio , for a particular ID , total number Y flag divided by the sum of Y and N flag

Comment: @Bharathshetty,added my expected output in question

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to groupby the column 'Shpr_ID'?

In that case, changing your code to:

```
Shpr_Resi_Ratio = (
    data[data.Resi == 'Y'].groupby(['Shpr_ID']).count() /
    float(data.groupby(['Shpr_ID']).count())
)
```

Should take care of that.

Comment: ,Its not calculating the ratio

Comment: Could this be caused by the counts not being floats? I’ve editted my answer to incoporate this.

Comment: It giving again error.TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DataFrame'

Comment: I am still getting erroe

Answer (score 0):

```
Shpr_ID_total=data.groupby(['Shpr_ID']).agg({'Shpr_ID': 'count'})
Shpr_ID_Y=data[data['Resi'] == 'Y'].groupby(['Shpr_ID']).agg({'Shpr_ID': 'count'})

def computeResi(Shpr_ID):
    ratio=0

    try:
        ratio=Shpr_ID_Y.Shpr_ID[Shpr_ID]/Shpr_ID_total.Shpr_ID[Shpr_ID]
    except:
        pass

    return ratio
```